# mod-rewrite overwrite all .php?

Tags: mod-rewrite

hey guys,
the following rule overwrites /signup.php with just /signup

```
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php
```

exactly what I want.
Since I have multipel .php files I don't want to create a custom rewrite rule for each file. How can I just overwrite all .php files with just the filename like the example above.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generic rule will help you.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$    $1.php
```